# Python large permutations

Tags: python, permutation

I'm working with a list that can range from 10-100 objects. Each object has specific variables assigned to it such as speed, cost, ect. The purpose of this is to find the a specific list out of all the list in the permutation.

The problem I'm running into is generating the permutation of 10 list, takes roughly 30 minutes. When I increase this to 12, 13... or more, the number of list becomes so much that running through each one takes so much time its pointless. What I currently have is the following:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for item in itertools.permutations(list):
   print(item)
```

This works great because it doesn't store the massive permutation list in RAM, but it does take a very long time. This is a shot in the dark, but is there any way I could speed up the process of looping over every list in the permutation?

Comment: I guess 99,9% of the runtime is printing to the screen. With an assignment instead of the print it takes less than a second.

Comment: Just something to remember, naming variables the same as built-ins (like list) in python is often problematic and always confusing. Try to avoid it.

Comment: @KlausD. you are right, but for number over 10 the possible permutation are way more (a list of 13 items has more than 6.2 billion permutations), so the problem will hit pretty fast also without the printing

Comment: Well, the more work you do the more time it takes. There is no magic command to do more work in less time.

Answer (score 1):

Stop printing your outputs. It will take a lot less time if you do that.